# Not allowing access to another computer in LAN

Tags: ip, xampp, local-area-network

Is it possible to handpick few ip addresses to allow access to localhost over LAN and rejecting other incoming connections? I am running XAMPP.

OS : Windows XP

Comment: Nitpick: `Localhost` is 127.0.0.1 and can not be accessed from LAN or any host other than itself.

Comment: XAMPP on Windows host?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to tell us the OS for more help

Comment: Its windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Create .htaccess file.

Inside place...

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168
allow from some.ip.address.1
allow from some.ip.address.2
```

This will allow from all LAN IP that start with 192.168, plus two specific additional IPs. Reject all others.